Default signal handler has priority over sigwait() when using raise()
I have C++ process running on ubuntu-22.04, that uses sigwait() to block the main thread until the process gets signaled to exit (with SIG_INT or SIG_TERM).
If it send the signal externally, this works fine (the sigwait() unblocks and the main thread completes), but if I try to raise() the signal internally (from withing the process itself) the sigwait() remains blocked and the signal is handled by the default signal handler as I do not have any custom handler installed.
My expectation is that calling raise(SIG_INT) would unblock sigwait() in the same way as if I use kill -INT <pid> command to raise the signal form the terminal, but this not appear to be the case.
As an alternative, I realized that I can use kill(getpid(), signal) method instead of raise() , which has the desired affect (sigwait() gets unblocked) but I am curious to why would raise(signal) behave differently.
Here is my wait method that uses sigwait (note that I explicitly try to block the default signal handler from being triggered for the stop signals):
int wait_stop_signals()
{
    sigset_t sigset;
    sigemptyset(&sigset);
    // Add the stop signals that we want to block and wait on
    sigaddset(&sigset, SIGINT);
    sigaddset(&sigset, SIGTERM);

    // Block the signal we are planning to wait for, so the default handlers are not triggered
    int rc = pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &sigset, nullptr);
    if (rc != 0) {
        return rc;
    }

    int sig = 0;
    // Block until one of the wait signals arrives
    return sigwait(&sigset, &sig);
}


As I was finishing writing the question and adjusting a bit the code example, I think I figured out the answer to my question.
The issues was that I was calling raise() from a different thread which apparently sends that signal only to that thread.
Here is a similar issue with the same root cause as for my issue.
